# Android dynamically Add multiple buttons

Tags: java, android

I am trying to dynamically add buttons in Android, the method i am using is only showing the last button of the loop though.

Here is the code i am using:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < SavedProducts.brands.size(); i++){
            Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 250);
            layoutParams.setMargins(80, 60, 80, 0);
            btn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            btn.setText(SavedProducts.brands.get(i).Name);
            Log.e("DISPLAYING NAME", SavedProducts.brands.get(i).Name+"");

            brandsList.addView(btn);
        }
```

While using this code, i only get one button at the top of the screen. My guess is that they are stacking on top of each other. How can i make the buttons appear stacked below each other?

Thanks.

brandsList in this context is a RelativeLayout.
The SavedProducts Object is populated properly.

EDIT: Im not sure if it makes a difference but i am trying to do this inside a fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was setting the margins in this line:

```
layoutParams.setMargins(80, 60, 80, 0);
```

The parameters for this function are setMargins(left margin, top margin, right margin, bottom margin).

Although I was adding the buttons dynamically, i was not changing the margin for each one, so they all appeared 60 pixels from the top of the view i was trying to add them to.

To fix this I made a new variable

```
int topMargin = i * 270;
```

As the height of each button is 250, this leaves a 20 pixel margin between each button.

I then put my new variable into the setMargins() function:

```
layoutParams.setMargins(80, topMargin, 80, 0);
```

This made the buttons appear below each other as i wanted them.

Answer (score 0):

Create the array of buttons outside of loop, and then add it to your layout.

```
Button btn[] =new Button[SavedProducts.brands.size()];

for(int i = 0; i < SavedProducts.brands.size(); i++){

btn[i]=new Button () ; 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 250); 
layoutParams.setMargins(80, 60, 80, 0); 
btn[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
btn[i].setText(SavedProducts.brands.get(i).Name); 
Log.e("DISPLAYING NAME", SavedProducts.brands.get(i).Name+"");

    brandsList.addView(btn[i] );
}
```

Comment: Cheers for your answer, with regards to setting up the buttons this is probably a better solution, however i did try this and due to the top margin remaining at 60, the issue i encountered would still be present

Comment: Put your layoutParam outside of loop this will probably work